# Infragistics 7.1 ultrawebgrid dropdown column - changed value disappears

Tags: infragistics

I'm working on a legacy application that uses VB.NET 2005 and Infragistics 7.1
I added a dropdownlist column to an ultrawebgrid. I see the dropdown filled with the correct values on cell click. But right after a new value is selected, the row just grays out and I cannot click on any other row.
What event/function is triggered on select of the dropdown? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a JavaScript error on the page that is preventing further interaction with the grid though there isn't enough detail in the question to actually know what that error may be.

The UltraWebGrid was only supported in IE and Firefox and for 2007 Volume 1 this would be Internet Explorer 6 or 7 and Firefox 2.  If you are using a newer version of either web browser than you should upgrade the Infragistics control to 2011 Volume 1 which would give you support for up to IE 9.  You can review the supported environments page [here](http://www.infragistics.com/help/supported-environments/).  If you need to obtain NetAdvantage 2011 Volume 1, you can download it from the [archived downloads page](http://www.infragistics.com/products/downloads/archived).

As far as debugging what is happening, if the issue happens in Firefox you can use firebug to do JavaScript debugging.  If you are using IE7, I believe that you are limited to using Visual Studio to do the debugging as the developer tools weren't included in IE7 and the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) didn't have JavaScript debugging.

If you are indeed using IE7 and need help with debugging the issue, you should provide a sample that reproduces the issue that someone else could use for debugging.